# Is it needed to INDEX second column for use in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing

Consider fetching data with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1='XX' && column2='XX'
```

Mysql will filter the results matching with the first part of WHERE clause, then with the second part. Am I right?

Imagine the first part match 10 records, and adding the second part filters 5 records. Is it needed to `INDEX` the second column too?

Comment: Try it out, it depends on your data set. Also, use the `EXPLAIN` feature of mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexes are optional in MySQL, but they can increase performance.

Currently, MySQL can only use one index per table select, so with the given query, if you have an index on both column1 and column2, MySQL will try to determine the index that will be the most beneficial, and use only one.

The general solution, if the speed of the select is of utmost importance, is to create a multi-column index that includes both columns.

This way, even though MySQL could only use one index for the table, it would use the multi-column index that has both columns indexed, allowing MySQL to quickly filter on both criteria in the WHERE clause.

In the multi-column index, you would put the column with the highest cardinality (the highest number of distinct values) first.

For even further optimization, ["covering" indexes](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/) can be applied in some cases.

Note that indexes can increase performance, but with some cost. Indexes increase memory and storage requirements. Also, when updating or inserting records into a table, the corresponding indexes require maintenance. All of these factors must be considered when implementing indexes.

**Update:** MySQL 5.0 can now use an index on more than one column by merging the results from each index, with a few caveats.

The following query is a good candidate for [Index Merge Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE key1=1 AND key2=1
```

Answer (score 5):

You are talking about **short circuit evaluation.** A DBMS has cost-based optimizer. There is **no** guarantee wich of both conditions will get evaluated first.

To apply that to your question: Yes, it might be benificial to index your second column.

- Is it used regulary in searches?
- What does the execution plan tell you?
- Is the access pattern going to change in the near future?
- How many records does the table contain?
- Would a Covering Index would be a better choice?
- ...

Answer (score 2):

When processing such query RDBMS will use only one index. Having separate indices on both colums will allow it to choose one that will be faster.

Whether it's *needed* depends on your specific situation.

- Is the query slow as it is now?
- Would it be faster with index on another column?
- Would it be faster with one index containing both
  columns?

You may need to try and measure several approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to INDEX the second column but it may speed up your SELECT